# Disconnected: No supported authentication methods for sudo user who authenticates using password

Tags: sudo, sshd, amazon-ec2, putty, amazon-linux

On an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance, password authentication from remote users has been enabled by running the following command during the `cloud-init` startup script: `sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`  .  As a result, remote users do not use a keypair to authenticate when logging in to the Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance.  One of those users, `someuser` , needs to be able to run `sudo` commands without typing in a password.

**Cloud-Init Startup Script**

The full `cloud-init` startup script is as follows:

```
/usr/sbin/useradd someuser
echo someuser:some-password | chpasswd
sed -i 's/PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
systemctl restart sshd  

cat << 'EOF' > /etc/sudoers.d/someuser
someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
EOF
```

**Question**

**What specific syntax needs to be used in the above `cloud-init` startup script in order to enable `someuser` to run `sudo` commands without restating their password, but while still enabling `someuser` to login remotely via Putty using their given password?**

**The error message**

The following screen shot illustrates the error message:

[image: Remote login rejected]

**Toggling The Error**

The above current syntax results in `someuser` not being able to Putty in due to a lack of a Public key.  However, the error can be removed, so that `someuser` is able to log in, but is NOT able to perform `sudo` commands, if the 3 line `cat` command is commented out of the above:

```
  #cat << 'EOF' > /etc/sudoers.d/someuser   
  #someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL   
  #EOF
```

The problem is in the preceding 3 lines posted here at the end.  How can these 3 lines be rewritten, replaced, or augmented to enable this user to elevate to `sudo` without a password while still retaining the ability to Putty in using only a password?

Comment: AFAIK `sshd` and `sudo` are orthogonal. Are you sure something else isn't failing in that script that is killing your `sshd` setup?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco  The problem is isolated to 3 lines that attempt to set up `sudo` access for `someuser`.  The OP asks precisely what you point out, which is **what is failing in these 3 lines?**

Comment: The rendering issue that appears in [revision 3](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/593519/3) of this question (code displayed as code in the preview, as normal text after the edit is saved) is interesting. With the aim of a bug report I tried to reproduce it in the [experimentation sandbox](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5590/315749) on Meta U&L (removing the actual text and keeping spacing, HTML tags and markdown), but I couldn't come up with any working repro steps.

Comment: someuser should belog to sudo group, i used to create new user like this:  `adduser someuser ;addgroup someuser; adduser someuser someuser; adduser someuser sudo`

Comment: @Jonah Your suggested code does not resolve the problem.  I commented out the part that removes the error as shown in the OP, then I added your code instead of the way the user is added in the OP, but the same error resulted.  I can still turn off the error by reverting to the non-sudo state shown in the OP.  I also added a screen shot of the error to the OP.  Can you have a look at the screen shot and suggest anything else?

Comment: i just added a new sudoer file as you did , and i broke my sudo , to get thing correct use visudo , `visudo -f /etc/sudoes.d/someuser ; # paste sudo rule , Ctrl+x , yes` this way visudo will prevent making changes in case of errors.

Comment: @Jonah Can you be absolutely explicit in the command you suggest?  So far what I have is `visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/someuser && someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: i apolgize , visudo here meant to open /etc/sudoers.d/someuser in nano conf/txt editor and you need to manually paste `someuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL` and save it , but you need non interactive commands to be add to that-init , sorry again, 
i am not used to clood-systems but wondering  doe's it removes the created user and sudo rules each time you logout/shutdown for that you recreate them each time ? o.O , if you can persistently do that , do it from root or other user that can use sudo (Note if other user can use sudo that means there no errors in sudoers files) check only user creation.

Comment: @Jonah The solution was to add this line `echo 'someuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo` immediately after the line in the OP that has the `chpasswd` command.  Of course, I also continued to comment out the lines that are commented out in the OP.  Your comment got me to find [this other posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323957/how-do-i-edit-etc-sudoers-from-a-script).  If you write an answer with this, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from `/etc/sudoers.d/README` :

It's **recommended** to use **visudo** ,
because it'll prevent making changes in case of errors ,
and also it'll deal with new file mode (**0440**).

which means your init script needed only a mode-change to the new created file (/etc/sudoers.d/someuser)

```
chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/someuser;
```

But the solution you did find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323957/how-do-i-edit-etc-sudoers-from-a-script) is better ,

```
echo 'someuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
```

Visudo here will use `tee` insteed of `nano` to append new content without **interaction** , and that's the magic that i missed!